# Modified Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

The algorithm for modified Gram-Schmidt (it does the same thing, but is supposed to be better for computers due to rounding) is:

0. For k=1,...,m

set $\tilde x_k=k_k$

1. Set $\tilde x_1=\tilde x_1/\|x_1\|$
2. For k=2,...,m

{

for j=k,...,m

{

set $\tilde x_j=\tilde x_j-\langle \tilde x_{k-1}, \tilde x_j\rangle\tilde x_{k-1}$

}

set $\tilde x_k=\tilde x_k/\|\tilde x_k\|$

}

I thought it'd be instructive to see what happens for m=3:

- Set $$\tilde x_1=\frac{x_1} {\|x_1\|}$$
- Set $$\tilde x_2=x_2-\langle \tilde x_1,x_2\rangle\tilde x_1$$
- Set $$\tilde x_3=x_3-\langle \tilde x_1,x_3\rangle\tilde x_1$$
- Set $$\tilde x_2=\frac{x_2-\langle \tilde x_1,x_2\rangle\tilde x_1}{\|x_2-\langle \tilde x_1,x_2\rangle\tilde x_1\|}$$
- Set $$\begin{split}\tilde x_3 &= x_3-\langle \tilde x_1,x_3\rangle\tilde x_1 - \langle\frac{x_2-\langle \tilde x_1,x_2\rangle\tilde x_1}{\|x_2-\langle \tilde x_1,x_2\rangle\tilde x_1\|}, x_3-\langle \tilde x_1,x_3\rangle\tilde x_1\rangle \frac{x_2-\langle \tilde x_1,x_2\rangle\tilde x_1}{\|x_2-\langle \tilde x_1,x_2\rangle\tilde x_1\|}\\
  &=x_3-\langle \tilde x_1,x_3\rangle\tilde x_1 - \langle \tilde x_2, x_3-\langle \tilde x_1,x_3\rangle\tilde x_1\rangle \tilde x_2\\
  &=x_3-\langle \tilde x_1,x_3\rangle\tilde x_1 - \langle \tilde x_2, x_3\rangle\tilde x_2\end{split}$$
- Set

$$\tilde x_3 = \frac{x_3-\langle \tilde x_1,x_3\rangle\tilde x_1 - \langle \tilde x_2, x_3\rangle\tilde x_2}{\|x_3-\langle \tilde x_1,x_3\rangle\tilde x_1 - \langle \tilde x_2, x_3\rangle\tilde x_2\|}$$

> Show that if the initial set of vectors are linearly independent, all
> residuals in the algorithm are nonzero. For $k\ge 2$, all that is
> required is to show that $\tilde x_k-\langle \tilde x_{k-1},\tilde
>  x_k\rangle \tilde x_{k-1}\ne 0$ if $\tilde x_k$ and $\tilde x_{k-1}$
> are linearly independent. Why?

It sounds like it's saying to take the difference between $\tilde x_k$ and the projection of the previous vector $\tilde x_{k-1}$ onto $\tilde x_k$. Since they are orthogonal, the projection would be the 0 vector. So we would be left with $\tilde x_k$. I'm not sure how this would show that the residuals are nonzero if the initial set of vectors is linearly independent.

Comment: If serious about an efficient numerically stable variation of Gram-Schmidt consider [Householder transforms](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2016/07/25/compare-gram-schmidt-and-householder-orthogonalization-algorithms/).  As a simple insight, rotate first, then rescale.  Rescaling and normalizing contribute larger rounding errors.